# Is there a formula to estimate index size in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, rdbms

How is it possible to calculate index size for specific column types in InnoDB i.e.:

- VARCHAR
- CHAR
- TIMESTAMP
- SMALLINT

I've found a formula for MyISAM (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/key-space.html): (key_length+4)/0.67

Does this work for InnoDB as well?

I'm trying to estimate the size of a database I'm designing for sizing purposes.

Answer (score 4):

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is embedded with the data, so you can think of it as taking no space.

For a secondary key...  Take the MyISAM formula, but include the columns of *both* the secondary key and the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then multiply by 3.  (There is a lot of overhead.)  Still, the answer can be off by a factor of 2 in either direction.

Note that if you have a lot of secondary keys, the size of the PK makes a big difference in the overall space for the table+indexes.

**Example**

```
SET @db = 'world', @tbl = 'cities';
    SELECT      n_rows AS 'Approx Rows',
                'Data & PK' AS 'Type',
                clustered_index_size * 16384 AS Bytes,
                ROUND(clustered_index_size * 16384 / n_rows) AS 'Bytes/row',
                clustered_index_size AS Pages,
                ROUND(n_rows / clustered_index_size) AS 'Rows/page'
        FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats
        WHERE database_name = @db
          AND table_name = @tbl
    UNION
        SELECT  n_rows,
                'Secondary Indexes' AS 'BTrees',
                sum_of_other_index_sizes * 16384 AS Bytes,
                ROUND(sum_of_other_index_sizes * 16384 / n_rows) AS 'Bytes/row',
                sum_of_other_index_sizes AS Pages,
                ROUND(n_rows / sum_of_other_index_sizes) AS 'Rows/page'
        FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats
        WHERE database_name = @db
          AND table_name = @tbl
          AND sum_of_other_index_sizes > 0
          ;
-- (Percona has a different way.)
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| Approx Rows | Type              | Bytes     | Bytes/row | Pages | Rows/page |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|     2637973 | Data & PK         | 179077120 |        68 | 10930 |       241 |
|     2637973 | Secondary Indexes | 232341504 |        88 | 14181 |       186 |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

The table has two indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(...)  -- 14 bytes
INDEX(state, population)
INDEX(state, city)
  state CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii -- 2 bytes
  population INT UNSIGNED -- 4 bytes
  city  -- AVG(LENGTH(city)) = 1+9.07 bytes

COUNT(*): 2,699,354  (the InnoDB estimate was not too far from this)

First index:  20    bytes * 2.7M rows = 54MB
Second index: 26.07 bytes * 2.7M rows = 70MB
Total:  124MB
Actual: 232MB
Ratio: 1.9x  (note: I skipped the "/0.67")
```

Just to prove another point, I tried `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  The stats after there were essentially the same:

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| Approx Rows | Type              | Bytes     | Bytes/row | Pages | Rows/page |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|     2685828 | Data & PK         | 179077120 |        67 | 10930 |       246 |
|     2685828 | Secondary Indexes | 232341504 |        87 | 14181 |       189 |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks. Is this somewhere on the documentation? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Not really.  The `*3` has been empirically derived over checking dozens of tables.  (And it might be much more or much less, depending on various things.)  Some of Jeremy Cole's blogs get into the gory details of how the data is stored.  If you go through the details, you might not get a better answer than my simplistic `*3` -- so many things impact the formulas.

Comment: At one extreme, a 1-row table, with one secondary index, will allocated a 16KB block for the data and another block for the index.  This is far more than `*3`.  An index can be fragmented or it can be freshly defragmented; this can make a difference of at least `*1.5`, probably more.  The `ROW_FORMAT` probably has some impact; I don't know how much.

Comment: The example I added came up with 1.9x instead if 3x.  This variation is to be expected.

Comment: `mysql.innodb_table_stats` is not available until MySQL 5.6 (in 2011) and MariaDB 10.0.  Before that, all you have is `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 2):

One secondary index record is indexed fields + primary key. Sum up field sizes, multiply by number of records, add some overhead and that would be index size.