# How to get InnoDB table index size on a replica running MariaDB 5.5?

Tags: innodb, mariadb

I tried adapting a [solution for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297107/96588), but it turns out `information_schema.innodb_table_stats` is empty. `SHOW INDEX FROM schema_name.table_name` doesn't cut it, by only showing cardinality.

Comment: The table shouldn't be empty. It will have different column names than `mysql.innodb_table_stats` from the mentioned answer, but the info should be there. Did you check it by a simple `select` from the table? Does it stay empty if you create a new InnoDB table? Does error log say anything about it? Which exactly MariaDB 5.5.x is it?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql.innodb_table_stats` is not available until MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 10.0.  Before that...

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename';
```

will provide `Data_length`, which is the amount of space taken by all indexes except the `PRIMARY KEY` (in the case of InnoDB).  There was no way to get the sizes of individual secondary indexes.  The PK is "clustered" with the data, so there is really very little space taken in addition to the data.

It is general inadvisable to have a Slave running an older version than the Master, if that is what you are doing.

What are you really looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for the size to figure out what the memory pressure is because of this index, and what I can expect it to be once I change the index. Both machines are running the exact same version of MariaDB on the same platform, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Indexes are only "cached" in RAM.  If, say, the index is chronologically ordered (id or datetime), and you only reference 'recent' rows, then the 'working set' is much less than the entire size.  If, on the other hand, accesses are random (or UUID index, which is random), then the size of the index _is_ relevant.